# rbind and join in data.table

Tags: r, join, data.table, bind

I need to `rbind(.)` two data.tables, one of which has two more columns than the other. I would like to bind them but also fill the columns.

```
d1 <- data.table(group=rep(1:2,each=5), no=1:5, x= rep(c(100,200), each=5), y=rnorm(10))
d2 <- data.table(group=rep(1:2,each=2), y=rnorm(4))

> rbind(d1,d2,fill=TRUE)
    group no   x            y
 1:     1  1 100  0.018938699
 2:     1  2 100 -1.924350449
 3:     1  3 100  0.331769790
 4:     1  4 100 -0.007978624
 5:     1  5 100 -0.216864548
 6:     2  1 200 -0.959552464
 7:     2  2 200 -0.878798805
 8:     2  3 200 -0.671132161
 9:     2  4 200 -1.329565254
10:     2  5 200  0.795662872
11:     1 NA  NA  0.312083392
12:     1 NA  NA -0.485818453
13:     2 NA  NA  1.848410165
14:     2 NA  NA  1.476295328
```

Most importantly, missing values of the `x` column should be filled the same way as all others in the same group. If possible, missing values of the `no` column should be continued. Is this possible in data.table? It appears to be some mix of binding and joining and I don't know how to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with some group operations on the rbind output

```
out <- 
  rbind(d1, d2, fill = T)[, `:=`(no = 1:.N, x = x[!is.na(x)][1]), by = group]

out
#     group no   x           y
#  1:     1  1 100  0.54925252
#  2:     1  2 100  1.10898571
#  3:     1  3 100 -0.06352423
#  4:     1  4 100 -0.39246382
#  5:     1  5 100 -0.06599473
#  6:     2  1 200 -0.92048106
#  7:     2  2 200 -0.45606083
#  8:     2  3 200 -1.12622400
#  9:     2  4 200  0.54906549
# 10:     2  5 200  1.11150729
# 11:     1  6 100 -2.03593356
# 12:     1  7 100 -0.22070918
# 13:     2  6 200 -0.48830888
# 14:     2  7 200 -1.36497717
```

You could do this with a join also (same output)

```
rbind(d1, d2[d1, on = 'group', `:=`(x = i.x, no = max(i.no))][, no := no + rowid(group)])
```

Comment: Your first way without the by= grouping: ```setorder(rbind(d1, d2, fill=TRUE), group)[, `:=`(no = rowid(group), x = nafill(x, "locf"))][]``` I think devel version may be required for `nafill`.

Comment: Yeah just checked and `nafill` is in devel 1.12.3. Great to hear though, I wasn't aware data.table was getting a `nafill` function! Now if I could get a `coalesce` I'd really be able to cut some packages out of some scripts. Edit: There's a `coalesce` in devel too! Wow!